# Deliver javascripts from jar

Tags: servlets, dwr

I have a java web application. Here I have some javascript files which I want to be inside a jar file. I want there will be a servlet which will deliver the javascript files from the jar. The feature is like [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org) library. They have some javascript files which is not included in the file system. Rather they deliver the javascripts from the jar. [DWRServlet](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/javadoc/org/directwebremoting/servlet/DwrServlet.html) class do that. But the path is included in the html header. I want to implement such a feature. Could you guys give me some idea how to implement that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources in JARs are part of the classpath. You can get an `InputStream` of a classpath resource by `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`. So, just let your Servlet do exactly that.

Assuming that you have those JS resources in `/META-INF/resources` of the JAR:

```
@WebServlet("/resources/*")
public class ResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getPathInfo();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/resources" + path);

        if (input != null) {
            response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(path));
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            // Now just write input to output the usual way.
        } else {
            response.sendError(404);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can get `/META-INF/resources/some.js` of the JAR by http://localhost:8080/contextname/resources/some.js.